# Why does '\xa' not appear when outputting echo "C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\myOnlineStore";

Tags: php, string, echo, dir

This line of code

echo "C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\myOnlineStore";

outputs

C: mpp\htdocs\practice\myOnlineStore

Why is the \xa omitted from the output? Is there some sort of special character involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\x` is a escape sequence that means:

> After "\x", up to two hexadecimal digits are read (letters can be in upper or lower case). In UTF-8 mode, "\x{...}" is allowed, where the contents of the braces is a string of hexadecimal digits. It is interpreted as a UTF-8 character whose code number is the given hexadecimal number. The original hexadecimal escape sequence, \xhh, matches a two-byte UTF-8 character if the value is greater than 127.

As the docs says [here](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)

So you have to escape all `escape chars` on your string like:

```
echo "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\practice\\myOnlineStore";
```

The `\` is also an escape character.

Answer (score 0):

escape `\` with `\\` it like this

```
echo "C:\\xampp\htdocs\practice\myOnlineStore";
```

***[see this](http://www.linuxcommand.org/wss0060.php)***

Comment: Didn't you mean to escape _all_ backslashes?

Answer (score 0):

backslash is a special escape character, it expects a special identifier next and does not interpret it directly as text.  If you actually want to print a backslash character you need to use '\'.  The first backslash starts an escape sequence, the second backslash tells the escape sequence that you just want a normal backslash.

Your string should look more like this:

```
C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\practice\\myOnlineStore
```

Or you can just use forward slashes instead:

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/practice/myOnlineStore
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace Double quotes with single quotes

```
echo 'C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\myOnlineStore';
```